# how can i reference form data from the referring document?

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a web page that opens up from another page after the user clicks a link. What i want to do using JS is reference the form data from the original page and use it on the page that has just been opened . my first page contains something like

```
 function date_change() {
  window.open("//www.abbeysoft.co.uk/adi/datepicker.php");
 }
```

Then i want to use something like the code below in page two

```
 nam = document.form1.name.value
```

is this something I can do easily

Any hints or pointers would be great

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.opener.document.forms["form1"].elements["fieldname"].value` will get you to the value of any object in a given form.

Comment: Well, as far as I'm concerned, `forms` is standard. You can always add an id to the form elements and use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

With [opener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.opener)